# Definable sets à la Jech

Tags: set-theory

Jech in [Set Theory, p. 175](http://books.google.de/books?id=WTAl997XDb4C&pg=PA175&dq=jech%20constructible%20sets&hl=de&sa=X&ei=NU7UUZ5j1IqFB-i1gNAJ&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=jech%20constructible%20sets&f=false) defines **definable sets** over a given model $(M,\in)$ (where $M$ is a set) as those sets (= subsets of $M$) $X$ with a formula $\phi$ in the set of formulas of the language $\lbrace \in \rbrace$ and some $a_1,\dots,a_n \in M$ such that

$$ X = \lbrace x \in M : (M,\in) \models \phi[x,a_1,\dots, a_n]\rbrace$$

Jech defines

$$ \text{def}(M) := \lbrace X \subset M : X\ \text{is definable over }\ (M,\in)\rbrace $$

So far, everything is clear to me.

But then, Jech claims:

> Clearly, $M \in \text{def}(M)$ and $M \subset \text{def}(M) \subset \text{P}(M)$.

It is clear to me that and why $M \in \text{def}(M)$ and that and why $\text{def}(M) \subset \text{P}(M)$. But I cannot see at once that and why $M \subset \text{def}(M)$ for arbitrary sets $M$.

Is this a typo in Jech's [Set Theory](http://books.google.de/books?id=WTAl997XDb4C) or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: Maybe he wanted to say $\forall x \in M: \{ x\} \in def (M)$.

Answer (score 3):

If $M$ is transitive and $a \in M$ then $a \subseteq M$ and moreover $$a = \{x \in M : (M,{\in}) \vDash x \in a\}.$$ So $a \in \operatorname{def}(M)$.

Comment: Furthermore, transitivity is absolutely essential here, because def$(M)$ consists of some subsets of $M$, so if $M\subseteq\text{def}(M)$ then all elements of $M$ are subsets of $M$.

Comment: I deleted the part of my question where I mention transitiveness (because Jech doesn't mention it neither). Or *does* he - somehow implicitely?

Comment: @Hans: Jech proceeds immediately to define $L$, and he claims, immediately that $L$ is a transitive class. It isn't hard to see that those claims are true because we started with a transitive $M$ (namely, the empty set). So yes, it does seem that Jech implicitly assumes that $M$ is a transitive set.

Answer (score 3):

It does seem like a typo in Jech. However we are going to be interested in transitive sets $M$, so it's not a big deal.

These mistakes *can* and *do* happen, a lot. They appear in every textbook, sometimes they are more prominent and sometimes less. Reading and learning you have to know when these typos, or mistakes, matter for the theorems of interest, and when they are not. In this case any issue is negligible, because in the next paragraph Jech defines $L_\alpha$ and $L$ and goes on to claim it's a transitive class.

But it's still a typo, for if $M$ is a non-transitive model then there is some $m\in M$ such that $m\nsubseteq M$. If $\operatorname{def}(M)\subseteq\mathcal P(M)$, then clearly $m\notin\operatorname{def}(M)$ and so $M\nsubseteq\operatorname{def}(M)$.

But for transitive $M$'s this is not an issue, of course as $a=\{x\in M\mid M\models x\in a\}$ for $a\in M$.

Comment: Surely $\varnothing^M$ is defined by $\forall y, y \not \in x$?

Comment: @Chris: No, I mean to say that $\varnothing^M$ is not an actual element of $\operatorname{Def}(M)$. Because it *does* contain elements (in the universe), whereas $\{m\in M\mid M\models m\in\varnothing^M\}$ is the real empty set.

Comment: Oh yes, of course. I'm confusing my definable elements with my definable sets.

Comment: Thanks, Asaf. That's what I hoped to get as an answer. But what is "a big deal" in a mathematical text? There are people - like me - that want to take such a text serious, rigorous, and 1:1. So it *is* a big deal, when someone like Jech claims that $M \subset \text{def}(M)$ for arbitrary sets $M$.

Comment: @Hans: I never wrote a book. Even my M.Sc. thesis only stretched over 50 pages including title and bibliography (and I had to write two titles, each including four pages, one in Hebrew and another in English). But I was told that when you write a book you *will* make these sort of mistakes, and plenty of them. Does that mean that no one can take any book that was ever written seriously? No. It just means that you need to keep track of possible implicit assumptions, and to know understand when they are relevant to the coming theorems, and when they are not.

Comment: I've said on several occasions that any (math) document more than 4 pages long will contain some error. That's probably not quite true, but it's very close to true. Once, the referee of one of my papers wrote in his report that he didn't find even a single typo; I took that as a challenge, and, sure enough, I found one.